# Conexion de aplicacion imagen docker con Entity Framework y PostgreSQL: 'schema not found' error

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, imagen, docker, microservices

¡Hola mundo!

Esoty desarrollando un microservicio que utiliza imagenes de docker con Entity framework y postgres. Sin embargo, cuando Entity trata de conectar postgres con el paquete Npgsql me retorna el siguiente mensaje que el schema no existe

Mi archivo `docker-compose.yml`:

```
`version: '3.7'
services:
  
  web:
    container_name: 'aspnetcoreapp'
    image: netcoreapi:latest
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
        - aspnetcoreapp-network
    volumes:
        - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: postgres
    environment:
      # change this for a "real" app!
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: db

    networks:
      - aspnetcoreapp-network

networks:
  aspnetcoreapp-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres-data:`
```

Luego establecí la conexion en `appsettings.json`

```
"Data": {
    "DbContext": {
       "ConnectionString":  "User ID=postgres;Password=password;Server=postgres;Port=5432;Database=db;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
   
    } `
```

Esta es la conexión en `Program.cs`:

```
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<SubjectDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Data:DbContext:ConnectionString")))
```

Este es mi `DbContext.cs`

```
using AspNetCorePostgreSQLDockerApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AspNetCorePostgreSQLDockerApp.Repository
{
    public class SubjectDbContext : DbContext
    {
      public SubjectDbContext (DbContextOptions<SubjectDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
       
          modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>(e => e.ToTable("subjects"));
          modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>(entity =>
          {
            entity.Property(e => e.CourseID)
                                .HasColumnName("id")
                                .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('account.item_id_seq'::regclass)");
            entity.Property(e => e.Title).IsRequired().HasColumnName("title");
            entity.Property(e => e.Credits).IsRequired().HasColumnName("credits");
          });
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      } 
      public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Pero cuando enciendo el container de Net core y Postgres con `docker-compose up` me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
 fail: Program[0] An error occurred creating the DB. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3F000: schema "account" does not exist
```

Si me pueden ayudar, estaria muy agradecido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en esta en la última línea de:

```
entity.Property(e => e.CourseID)
   .HasColumnName("id")
   .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('account.item_id_seq'::regclass)")
```

Ahí haces referencia a `account` que por el resto del código no se aprecia que exista.

Si entiendo bien ese código, lo que estas tratando de hacer es que sea auto incrementable, prueba con esto

```
entity.Property(e => e.CourseID)
   .HasColumnName("id")
   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```